# where does access point's IP address come from for wifi.beginAP() on Arduino MKR1000?

Tags: arduino, network-programming, wifi, arduino-mkr1000

I don't understand where the access point's IP comes from. Sketch uses WiFi.beginAP( ssid ) ..to start the AP. Then, printWifiStatus() gets the access point's IP with: IPAddress ip = WiFi.localIP();

How does .beginAP() create the IP? What does it use for a mask?

I'm creating network service on a MKR1000, and want to use .beginAP() to make it an access point, so I don't need a "middle man" (router). Going to have mobile device (iPhone) connect directly to Arduino MKR1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same question as on [arduino.stackexchange.com](http://arduino.stackexchange.com).

In short: If you look into that GitHub source code, you can see `startAP` function and mainly rows with `strM2MAPConfig.au8DHCPServerIP`.

Comment: AP is 192.168.1.1